# template function overloading c++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm working on a generic matrix class.
I to overload the + function, so that when is do :

1. matrix = scalar * matrix
2. matrix = matrix * scalar
3. matrix = matrix * matrix

Tried to do it like that (function overloading):
Is it a right way to do it ?

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    std::vector< std::vector<T> > mat;
    size_t rows , cols;

public:
    Matrix(){}
    Matrix(const std::string){  }
    Matrix(const size_t r, const size_t c, const std::vector<T> v){ }
    Matrix(const Matrix& other);

    Matrix<T> operator=(const Matrix<T> &other)  {  }

    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &other) const{}

    friend Matrix<T> operator*(const T &mat, const Matrix<T> &scalar) { }

    friend Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> &mat, const T &scalar) { }

    friend Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> &mat, const Matrix<T> &other) {  }
```

Also I'll be glad to know if there is some problems with my declarations. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Reminder: you need to do both the implementation and the declaration in the header file

Comment: It would be nice to show your problem instead of requesting code review.

Comment: And I suspect your assignment operator should return `Matrix&`. Also, not sure why that `std::string` is `const` in that alternate-ctor; try a const-reference.

Comment: It's no a problem Just want to know if thats how I should do it.
@WhozCraig you right i'll fix it.

May be I should return a reference ? or const reference ? or to make the  function const ?

Comment: @IgorGumush _" or const reference ? or to make the function const ?"_ Certainly not for the assignment operator, for the mathematical operations and comparison operations it should be definitiely considered. Also note: There's a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE site, that is better suited for such questions.

Comment: Consider dropping the `template` part until you got the whole thing working, it only complicates things at first.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ should I copy it to the code Review or the code is ok ? thanks

Comment: @IgorGumush You should post your question there, yes. You'll get similar answers as from our previous commnents, but as answers and more detailed perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overload `operator*` to allow

1. matrix = scalar * matrix
2. matrix = matrix * scalar
3. matrix = matrix * matrix

you need to define these three operator overloads as functions in the namespace surrounding the matrix class:

```
class Matrix { ... };
Matrix operator*(Scalar const& s, Matrix const& m) { ... }
Matrix operator*(Matrix const& m, Scalar const& s) { ... }
Matrix operator*(Matrix const& m1, Matrix const& m2) { ... }
```

In your case, you declared the operators as `friend` functions inside the class, which does the same because it actually declares free functions *and* makes them `friends`. It depends on the implementation if the `friend` is actually necessary. If not, I'd move them outside the class for clarity, but keep in mind that you will need `template<typename T>` then. Concerning the rest of the code, there is nothing that is visibly broken, but it is only an excerpt of the real code anyway.

Comment: I tried that , but how would I know the first two states.
1. template<typename T> 
   Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*( const Matrix<T> &scalar) 
2. template<typename T> 
   Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*( const T &scalar)

like this ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you tried, but there seems to be some confusion between free functions and memberfunctions. I'll try to clarify what I wrote.

Comment: By saying "friend is actually necessary" what do you meen ? When does it's necessary?

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the question, had a alternate idea.

```
matrix = scalar * matrix
matrix = matrix * scalar
matrix = matrix * matrix
```

alternative way would be to use the function objects and pass them to the matrix class, so that function objects could handle the algorithm specifics...This allows you to add some more later on if needed.

Operator chaining would also be handy in the above code,hence, return by reference for overloaded operators.

Comment: What would the reference refer to in a binary operation?

Comment: I meant the resultant matrix object if you are planning to do it in place.